# Ending a survey - best practice?

Tags: 2010, survey

I created a survey in SP2010 using the OOB option (no extraneous coding). I found no way to end the survey through permissions or what have you, so ended up limiting who had access to it (eliminated permissions). **Is there an easy way to end the survey, or something I missed?** I found other posts on how to put a time limit on them through a programatical means, but nothing about just putting a stop to the survey (no longer allowing input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the only way I know of is to revoke access or mark everyone as read only.

Comment: I hadn't considered marking everyone as read only. That seems like a good way to go as well. It would allow everyone involved to still have access to their input and see others input if the survey allows. Thanks for your response.